# Junit NullPointerException and I don't understand why

Tags: java, junit

I am trying to understand what is causing my test to throw a null pointer exception. I don't understand if I am not properly using mocks or something?

```
class OrderServiceImplTest {
OrderServiceImpl orderService;

@Mock
OrderDao orderDao;

@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    orderService = new OrderServiceImpl(orderDao);
}

@Test
void cancelOrder() {
    Integer id = 1;
    Order mockOrder = new Order(1, 1, null, null, 1, null, 1);
    Order expectedResult = new Order(1, 5, null, null, 1, null, 1);

    Mockito.when(orderDao.getById(id)).thenReturn(mockOrder);
    Mockito.when(orderDao.save(expectedResult)).thenReturn(expectedResult);

    Order actualResult = orderService.cancelOrder(id);
    assertEquals(expectedResult,actualResult);
}
```

Here are the methods in the service class that I would like to create unit tests for:

```
@Override
public Order placeOrder(Order order) {
    if(order.getLineItems().size() == 0){
        return null;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < order.getLineItems().size(); i++) {
        if(order.getLineItems().get(i).getPrice().compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) < 0 ||
           order.getLineItems().get(i).getName() == null ||
           order.getLineItems().get(i).getName().length() == 0 ||
           order.getLineItems().get(i).getQuantity().compareTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(1)) < 0){
            return null;
        }
        order.getLineItems().get(i).setOrder(order);
        order.getLineItems().get(i).setNumber(i+1);
    }

    return this.orderDao.save(order);
}

@Override 
public Order cancelOrder(Integer id) {
    Order orderToCancel = this.orderDao.getById(id);

    if(orderToCancel.getStatusId() != 3 && orderToCancel.getStatusId() != 4){
        orderToCancel.setStatusId(5);
        return this.orderDao.save(orderToCancel);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Is it the methods themselves that need to be refactored in some way, or am I missing something silly?

Edit
Here is the stack trace.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.tli.orders.services.OrderServiceImplTest.cancelOrder(OrderServiceImplTest.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

Comment: What's the complete stack trace for the exception? That should be your first source of information on the issue and you need to post it if you want us to look for a cause.

Comment: Please learn to read stacktraces `orderserviceimpltest.java:52` tells you on exact what line the NPE is. That should give you a good guess before asking on stack overflow

Comment: @Toerktumlare I know how to read stacktraces. This didn't help. I obviously checked the stacktrace before coming here.

Comment: Looking at the stack trace should show you that your mock was null. That should in turn lead you to start reading what the annotation does, and how it works, and also read the full chapter on mocks in spring which is very well documented in the spring boot documentation on their webpage. Im just trying to help you help yourself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what you have shown, you are not initializing your mock's. There are cleaner ways to do this (which varies based on if you are using JUnit 4 or 5, so please specify if you would like help with that), but for the sake of finding the problem, can you try the following `setup` method:

```java
@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    orderDao = Mockito.mock(OrderDao.class);
    orderService = new OrderServiceImpl(orderDao);
}
```

Comment: Is that not what the @Mock on the orderDao object does?

Comment: That's the reasonable thought process when you first start using this library, but unfortunately not how it actually works. It simply labels the field as one you want to mock so that (when you use a cleaner setup like I'd mentioned) Mockito can dynamically initialize them. Until Mockito is told to initialize those fields, the `@Mock` annotation is pretty much useless.